# Why does MPC-HC playback freeze when I scroll through web pages in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, freeze, browsing

I am using Mozilla Firefox 47.0.1 on Windows 10 Pro. The PC has a Core i7 vPro processor, with 8GB RAM. When I browse through web pages (such as Facebook, Quora), MPC-HC playback freezes and flashes for about 10-20 seconds before resuming. This does not happen when I am not using Firefox. My device drivers are up-to-date (according to Windows Update). To be double sure, I manually updated the Intel and NVIDIA display drivers. What could be causing this freezing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching the playback output in MPC-HC: In MPC-HC, select View, Options. Then under Playback, Output, change the DirectShow Video to something else. Video Mixing Renderer 9 (Renderless) for me has been working great.  If that doesn't work, go down the list and try all the other different ones.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying the Video Mixer Renderer 9 (renderless). So far, no problems.